# Removing file after delivering response with Silex/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm generating a pdf using Knp\Snappy\Pdf in my Silex application.  the file name is random and saved to the tmp directory.

```
$filename = "/tmp/$random.pdf"
$snappy->generate('/tmp/body.html', $filename, array(), true);
```

I think return the pdf in the response,

```
$response = new Response(file_get_contents($filename));
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

return $response;
```

The pdf is displayed in the web browser correctly.  The file with the random filename still exists when the request is finished.  I can't unlink the file before returning the response.  I've tried registering a shutdown function with register_shutdown_function and unlinking the file from there. However that doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `BinaryFileResponse` for files, it takes care of the headers for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [finish](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/middlewares.html#finish-middleware) middleware for that:

> A finish application middleware allows you to execute tasks after the Response has been sent to the client (like sending emails or logging)

This is how it could look:

```
$app->finish(function (Request $request, Response $response) use ($app) {
    if (isset($app["file_to_remove"])) {
        unlink($app["file_to_remove"];
    }
});

//in your controller
$app["file_to_remove"] = $filename;
```

Answer (score 12):

Even though this is old, figured if anyone googles this more recently like I did. This is the solution I found.

There is a deleteFileAfterSend() method on the [BinaryFileResponse](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/BinaryFileResponse.html) returned from [sendFile](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#sending-a-file) in Silex.
So in your controller you can just do:

```
    return $app ->sendFile($filepath)
                ->setContentDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_INLINE, $fileName)
                ->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maerlyn is right, but in this case you can also unlink the file before returning the response, since the content of the file is already in the $response.